# [swagger angular client]:TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, swagger

I am working on angular js app. I am trying to use the module "Swagger angular client" to generate api. I am using the following swagger angular client module: ["signalfx:swagger-angular-client"](https://github.com/signalfx/swagger-angular-client)

I have made a simple swagger schema in order to understand this module. But I got this error in the google chrome inspector :

```
angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at processSchema (_prelude.js:102)
    at createClient (_prelude.js:11)
    at swaggerClient.js:32
    .................
    .............
```

I don't where the root cause of this issue. It seems like the swagger angular module does not accept my swagger schema.

Someone could help to solve this issue please ?

Thank you advance for your help!

**Here is my app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['swagger-client']);
```

**Here is my index:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="swagger-angular-client.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="mySwaggerFactory.js"></script>
  <script src="myController.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="Maincontroller">
          <h1>Swagger Angular</h1>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Here is my factoty**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myApi', ['swaggerClient', function(swaggerClient){

  var schema={
     "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "description" : "Tidiane application store.",
    "version" : "0.1",
    "title" : "Tidiane application store.",
    "contact" : {
      "name" : "Tidiane"
    },
    "license" : {
      "name" : "TODO: thanks for asking, yes it's copyrighted, I have to ask our jurists.",
      "url" : "http://licenseUrl"
    }
  },
  "host" : "replace.me.please",
  "basePath" : "/api/0.1",
  "tags" : [ {
    "name" : "services"
  }, {
    "name" : "user"
  } ],
  "paths" : {
      "/services/applications/{applicationID}" : {
      "get" : {
        "tags" : [ "services" ],
        "summary" : "find one application by its id",
        "description" : "",
        "operationId" : "getApplicationById",
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "applicationID",
          "in" : "path",
          "description" : "The application id",
          "required" : true,
          "type" : "string"
        } ],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "successful operation",
            "schema" : {
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/ApplicationData"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions" : {
    "ApplicationInfo" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "required" : [ "name" ],
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "example" : "slkkdiijqhq__çç_çç",
          "description" : ""
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "example" : "Service",
          "description" : "The short name"
        }
      },
      "description" : "short info about application"
    },
    "ApplicationData" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "required" : [ "applicationType", "deploymentMode", "description", "isEnabled", "name", "theme" ],
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "example" : "ç__z_z_è-d-xhjsyuhdycy",
          "description" : "description"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "example" : "Services 1",
          "description" : "The short name"
        },
        "applicationType" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "example" : "INTERNAL",
          "description" : "Application description"
        },
        "deploymentMode" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "example" : "UNIQUE",
          "description" : "Application description."
        },
        "description" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "description" : "Description of the application"
        },
        "dateTime" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "format" : "date-time",
          "example" : "2016-01-01",
          "description" : "Creation date of the application",
          "readOnly" : true
        },
        "isEnabled" : {
          "type" : "boolean",
          "example" : true,
          "description" : "Application description.",
          "default" : false
        },
        "theme" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "example" : "Service Management",
          "description" : "the name of the Service"
        }
        }
      }
    }
};
  return {
   // Instantiates the swagger-angular-client
        getApi: function(){
            var api = swaggerClient(schema);
            console.log("this api", api);

            return api;
          }
        };
}]);
```

**Here is my controller**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('Maincontroller',['$scope','myApi',function($scope, myApi){
    $scope.api = myApi.getApi();
}]);
```